# Reposition contents of NSImageView

Tags: cocoa, nsimageview

I have an NSImageView object sized to a specific aspect ratio. The view is set up as editable and I can drag and drop images into it. How do I set it up so the user can drag the embedded image around, effectively reframing it within the frame of the imageView?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should be thinking about dragging the imageView itself inside another view instead of dragging the image inside the imageView. Otherwise you would have to subclass NSImageView to do what you want, which seems far more convoluted than just dragging the NSImageView.